# Add a column in a dataframe which will include the average of the frequencies of specific number of observations

Tags: r

I have the dataframe below with dates and their frequency. I would like to add a third column which would estimate the average of the previous seven days. Given the fact that this can work from `'2020-09-18'` and later since previous dates do not have data for 7 days ,as first date is `'2020-09-12'`, the averages from `2020-09-12` until `2020-09-17` should be calculated based on the amount of previous days that exist otherwise they should be left with `NAs`

```
date<-c(as.Date("2020-09-15", "%Y-%m-%d"),as.Date("2020-09-14", "%Y-%m-%d"),
        as.Date("2020-09-13", "%Y-%m-%d"),as.Date("2020-09-12", "%Y-%m-%d"),
        as.Date("2020-09-15", "%Y-%m-%d"),as.Date("2020-09-14", "%Y-%m-%d"),
        as.Date("2020-09-13", "%Y-%m-%d"),as.Date("2020-09-12", "%Y-%m-%d"),
        as.Date("2020-09-16", "%Y-%m-%d"),as.Date("2020-09-17", "%Y-%m-%d"),
        as.Date("2020-09-18", "%Y-%m-%d"),as.Date("2020-09-19", "%Y-%m-%d"),
        as.Date("2020-09-20", "%Y-%m-%d"),as.Date("2020-09-21", "%Y-%m-%d"),
        as.Date("2020-09-22", "%Y-%m-%d"),as.Date("2020-09-23", "%Y-%m-%d"),
        as.Date("2020-09-24", "%Y-%m-%d"),as.Date("2020-09-25", "%Y-%m-%d"),
        as.Date("2020-09-26", "%Y-%m-%d"),as.Date("2020-09-27", "%Y-%m-%d"),
        as.Date("2020-09-28", "%Y-%m-%d"),as.Date("2020-09-29", "%Y-%m-%d"),
        as.Date("2020-09-30", "%Y-%m-%d"),as.Date("2020-10-01", "%Y-%m-%d"))
value<-c(5,6,7,8,-3,-5,6,8,5,6,7,8,-3,-5,6,8,5,6,7,8,-3,-5,6,8)
df<-data.frame(date,value)
df2<-data.frame(table(df$date))
```

Comment: what is the expected result for a few of them?

Comment: for example for 2020-09-18 should be (2+2+2+2+1+1+1)/7 for 2020-09-17 should be (2+2+2+2+1+1)/6

Comment: why should the 2020-09-17 be divided by 6 instead of NA?

Comment: because I guess it will give me NAs as result and I will not be able to plot it later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`frollmean` is a memory-efficient and fast solution from the excellent `data.table` package.

```
library(data.table)
# define the window for each element
adaptiveparam <- c(1:6, rep(7, nrow(df)-6))
df$rollmean <- frollmean(df$value, n=adaptiveparam, adaptive = T)
> head(df,8)
        date value rollmean
1 2020-09-15     5 5.000000
2 2020-09-14     6 5.500000
3 2020-09-13     7 6.000000
4 2020-09-12     8 6.500000
5 2020-09-15    -3 4.600000
6 2020-09-14    -5 3.000000
7 2020-09-13     6 3.428571
8 2020-09-12     8 3.857143
```

Here we define an `adaptive` vector specifying which window we want to average over, for each element of `df$value`.

Note that the analytical `data.table` syntax would be:

```
df[,rollmean:= frollmean(value, n=c(1:6, rep(7, nrow(df)-6)), adaptive = T)]
```

---

EDIT: also note that

```
library(lubridate)
as_date(c("2020-09-15", "2020-09-14"))
```

or even

```
date <- as_date("2020-09-15")+0:23
```

work as well to create date vectors, no need to use `as.Date` repeatedly.

---

EDIT2 for `df2` just modify as follows:

```
adaptiveparam2 <- c(1:6, rep(7, nrow(df2)-6))
df2$rollmean <- frollmean(df2$Freq, n=adaptiveparam2, adaptive = T)
```

Comment: it should be added to df2

Comment: but df2 has no 'value' variable so im not getting a new column

Answer (score 2):

In base R, you could do:

```
transform(df2, moving_average = filter(Freq, rep(1/7,7),sides = 1))
         Var1 Freq moving_average
1  2020-09-12    2             NA
2  2020-09-13    2             NA
3  2020-09-14    2             NA
4  2020-09-15    2             NA
5  2020-09-16    1             NA
6  2020-09-17    1             NA
7  2020-09-18    1       1.571429
8  2020-09-19    1       1.428571
9  2020-09-20    1       1.285714
10 2020-09-21    1       1.142857
11 2020-09-22    1       1.000000
12 2020-09-23    1       1.000000
13 2020-09-24    1       1.000000
14 2020-09-25    1       1.000000
15 2020-09-26    1       1.000000
16 2020-09-27    1       1.000000
17 2020-09-28    1       1.000000
18 2020-09-29    1       1.000000
19 2020-09-30    1       1.000000
20 2020-10-01    1       1.000000
```

You could also use `rollmeans` from `zoo` library: `transform(df2, v = zoo::rollmean(Freq, 7,NA))` This gives you the same results when `sides = 2`

EDIT:

if you do not need the NAs but still using base R:

```
transform(df2, moving_average = c(cumsum(Freq[1:6])/1:6,filter(Freq, rep(1/7,7),sides = 1)[-(1:6)]))
         Var1 Freq moving_average
1  2020-09-12    2       2.000000
2  2020-09-13    2       2.000000
3  2020-09-14    2       2.000000
4  2020-09-15    2       2.000000
5  2020-09-16    1       1.800000
6  2020-09-17    1       1.666667
7  2020-09-18    1       1.571429
8  2020-09-19    1       1.428571
9  2020-09-20    1       1.285714
10 2020-09-21    1       1.142857
11 2020-09-22    1       1.000000
12 2020-09-23    1       1.000000
13 2020-09-24    1       1.000000
14 2020-09-25    1       1.000000
15 2020-09-26    1       1.000000
16 2020-09-27    1       1.000000
17 2020-09-28    1       1.000000
18 2020-09-29    1       1.000000
19 2020-09-30    1       1.000000
20 2020-10-01    1       1.000000
```

Comment: please check that this is correct, as I have an `Error in UseMethod("filter_") : 
  no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')" ` : `transform(df2, moving_average = filter(Freq, rep(1/7,7),sides = 1))`

Comment: @CatalystRPA that is because you have masked `filter` by other packages. `filter` that I am using resides in the base R package. If you have loaded tidyverse for example, the filter will be masked. You should consider using `stats::filter` or restart rstudio without calling any libraries. But you should definitely be able to use `stats::filter(Freq, rep(1/7,7), sides=1)`

Comment: Since dplyr is the culprit it might be better to use `library(dplyr, exclude = c("lag", "filter"))` and then use `dplyr::filter` and `dplyr::lag` to prevent it from overwriting base functions.  Can then still access dplyr versions using `dplyr::filter` and `dplyr::lag` while normal `lag` and `filter` will then continue to have their usual menaing.